# Duda con script PHP

Tags: php

tengo una duda con script PHP que tengo formulado:

Primeramente, tengo un botón cuya función es eliminar una fila seleccionada según su id:

```
<?php foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $proveedor){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $proveedor['id'] ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $proveedor['nombre'] ?></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-block btn-warning" href=""><i class="fa fa-edit">EDITAR</i></a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-block btn-danger" href="<?php echo "php/eliminar_proveedor.php?id=" . $proveedor['id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit">ELIMINAR</i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Este btn está enlazado con otro script PHP cuyo problema, no estaría comprendiendo.
Dicho script es el siguiente:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET["id"])){
    if (isset($_GET["id"])){
        if($_GET["id"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";

            $found = false;
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE id = \"$_GET[id]\"";

            $query = $con->query($sql1);

            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()){

                $found = true;
                break;
            }
            if ($found){
            print "<script>alert(\"Algo salió mal.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
            }

            $sql = "DELETE FROM proveedores WHERE id = $_GET[id]";
            print $sql;
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Proveedor eliminado.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

El script aparentemente funciona correctamente, es decir, al apretar el botón, la fila se elimina, sin embargo, el mensaje que sale como alert es el de ALGO SALIÓ MAL, es decir, ese mensaje estaría programado para saltar si algo salió mal, pero claramente, todo salió bien.

Quisiera saber por qué el script estaría saltando ese mensaje, cuando debería saltar el mensaje de PROVEEDOR ELIMINADO que está al final y estaría programado para saltar cuando todo funcione bien.

Cualquier duda, estoy en los comentarios.

Comment: Por cierto que un rato antes de publicar esta pregunta, publicaste otra pregunta similar a esta, que tras haberla respondido pienso que correctamente, la has borrado en lugar de marcar la solución como correcta. No creo que sea la forma de corresponder el esfuerzo que se emplea en responder.

Comment: Asi es, me di cuenta que el problema había sido otro, y cuando empecé a formular las ediciones, se me estaba haciendo todo muy confuso. Mis disculpas, en esta te doy la respuesta como correcta. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donde pone

```
        if ($found){
```

debes poner

```
        if (!$found){
```

(si no encuentra el registro, entonces muestra el mensaje de algo salió mal)

Quizás, también deberías poner `return;` tras mostrar el `alert()` si quieres que interrumpa la ejecución.

Comment: Sos un genio!, ya me habías contestado una pregunta anterior y de manera correcta. Pero la tuve que eliminar porque el problema que tenía era otro. En breve te doy la respuesta. Mil gracias!

Comment: el código que propocionas no te dice si existió un error o no al ejecutar la consulta de base de datos, solo te dice  si existe o no un registro en la tabla proveedores de la base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo cambiar

```
 $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Proveedor eliminado.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
            }
```

Por algo como esto:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     print "<script>alert(\"Proveedor eliminado.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
} else {
    print "<script>alert(\"Error eliminando proveedor.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
}
```

Cuando realizas:

```
if ($found)
```

Solo preguntas si existe el registro en base de datos, no quiere decir que sea un error como tal de la acción de eliminar.

Al realizar un IF / ELSE con la acción de eliminar, si estamos verificando si se ejecuto de manera correcta o no la sentencia de SQL.

Ya que la variable `$found` solo sirve para confirmar si existe o no en base de datos un proveedor con el ID a eliminar, para eliminar un proveedor e informar de algún error o no, el código debería ser algo como esto:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET["id"])){
    if (isset($_GET["id"])){
        if($_GET["id"]!=""){
            include "conexion.php";


            $sql = "DELETE FROM proveedores WHERE id = $_GET[id]";
            print $sql;
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                  #tu mensaje de confirmación
            } else {
                  #tu mensaje de error al ejecutar la sentencia $sql
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Comprendo, lo del error es básicamente el mensaje. Con el script me saltaba el mensaje que no debería haber pasado. Guardo tu respuesta para desarrollar otros scripts. Gracias! muy útil!

Comment: @JoseManuelBorras toda acción previo al eliminar (me refiero al select y su ejecución esta demás si la "responsabilidad" de tu modulo php es eliminar ). modificare mi respuesta para un mejor ejemplo